# Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Storage' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror, web.py

I am learning Python 2.7 and trying to write a function in a module named *new5.py* like this:

```
def compare(a,b,c):
    if a - 3 == 8:
        return "I like a!"
    elif b == c:
        return "I like c!"
    else:
        return "I like b!"
```

When I try to call the function in the moudle named *app02.py* which is presented with detail code at the end of the qustion, I am told like this as presented as the following on the screen shot:

[image: TypeError description Screen Shot]

I guess the problem is on `a`, but what should I do to use the function? Thank you!

------ the following is the module app02.py rooted from web.py 0.3------

```
import web
import new5

urls = (
    '/dyear', 'Index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('/Users/Administrator/projects/gothonweb/templates/', base="layout01")


class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form01()

    def POST(self):
        form01 = web.input(a_year=1980)
        form02 = web.input(a_month=01)
        form03 = web.input(a_day=01)

        greeting = "Your result from app02 is %s" % (new5.compare(form01, form02, form03))
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Comment: What are the values of a, b and c that you pass to the function when you call the function?

Comment: For what line do you get the error? Please give us the complete error message.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I added more details with edits on the question, including adding an error message screen shot. Please give me a suggestion. @Flaming_Dorito

Comment: @supra28, thank you guy! I detailed on how to call the function in the new edits. Please advise.

Comment: `web.input` is returning a type `Storage` which does not define how to subtract from it. To do that it would probably have to implement the `__sub__` dunder method. To fix it you will have to figure out how to extract the required int value form the `Storage` object and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the whole `Storage` object to compare(), you should access a_year in form01, a_month in form02 and a_day in form03 objects like `form01.a_year`, `form2.a_month` or `form3.a_day`
So your function call should look something like

```
greeting = "Your result from app02 is %s" % (new5.compare(form01.a_year, form02.a_month, form03.a_day))
```

Also, note this from the [docs](http://webpy.org/cookbook/input)

> Note that the web.input() values will be strings even if there are
>   numbers passed to it.

so you'll need to typecast your web.input from string to the required type(here int) like so

```
if int(a) - 3 == 8:
```

Comment: Thank you so much! @Priya, I solved the problem with your advice.